# Функция для заполнения структуры

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Создал функцию set для заполнения структуры time:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct time
{
    int sec;
    int min;
    int chas;
};
time t;
void set(int s,int m, int c)
{
    t.sec=s;
    t.min=m;
    t.chas=c;
}
int main()
{
    int s,m,c;
    cout<<"Enter date";
    cin>>s>>m>>c;
    set(s,m,c);
    cout<<t.chas<<t.min<<t.sec;
    return 0;
}
```

Это хорошо или есть способ сделать эту функцию лучше?

Вот переделал код, так лучше?

Насчет имен я не стал писать правильноб а просто первое что в голову пришло т.к. проект пишу в учебных целях.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct time
{
    int sec;
    int min;
    int chas;
};
void set(time &t)
{   
    int s,m,c;
    cout<<" Enter sec ";
    cin>>s;
    cout<<" Enter min ";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<" Enter chas ";
    cin>>c;
    t.sec=s;
    t.min=m;
    t.chas=c;
}
void print(time &t)
{
    cout<<" chas "<<t.chas<<" min "<<t.min<<" sec "<<t.sec;
}
int main()
{
    time t;
    set(t);
    print(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Плохо то, что вместо "час" поле названо [бац!](http://slovari.yandex.ru/chas/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/#lingvo/)...

Comment: @klopp, не все "супер-пупер программисты" знакомы с английским =)

Comment: hour  
первый как-то покрасивее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Всегда есть способы сделать что-то лучше =)** Так, в вашем случае еще до совершенства, как мне до балерины.

1. Сразу бросается в глаза ИМЯ функции-сеттера **set**. Если в дальнейшем вы будете использовать контейнерные классы, а конкретно std::set, то в некоторых( если не во всех ) компиляторах может возникнуть путаница по поводу имен.
2. А если имя переменной типа **time** решено будет изменить, например на tt или ttt. Будет неудобно все это переписывать, поэтому я предложил бы вам передавать в функцию указатель на структуру и последующие целочисленные параметры. При чем, если параметры однотипные, можно было бы использовать массив общего типа для дальнейшего расширения, если таковое вообще планируется.
3. Сам по себе вынос переменной за пределы функций в си не считается хорошим стилем( time t; ). Вы так поступаете, чтобы, само собой, взаимодействовать с переменной в функции, тем самым портите стиль.
4. Также, думаю, было бы неплохо создать в структуре базовый конструктор, который бы инициализировал все поля нулями( если имеем дело с циферками=) )

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал 2 функции для заполнения струтуры. Одна, почти как во втором варианте, а вторая почти как в первом

```
int readtime (time *pt)
{
    ...
    cin >> pt->sec;
    ...
    return cin.good();
}
void settime (time *pt, int s, int m, int c)
{
   ...
   pt->sec = s;
   ...
}
```

Это, как говорится дело вкуса, но я лично не люблю запись вида

```
f(time &t) { ... }
```

поскольку ей соответствуют вызовы вида

```
f(t);
```

и если не помнить прототип (или описание параметров функции), то при чтении кода всегда кажется (сходу так читается), что в функцию передается не адрес структуры (что на самом деле в Вашей записи и происходит), а ее содержимое.

Мне кажется, лучше явно писать с указателями.